# Are TCN BPDUs dropped on their way to the root if "message age" gets higher then "max age"?

Tags: spanning-tree

Normal BPDU gets [discarded](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46173/what-happens-when-a-bpdu-message-age-reaches-max-age) if the message age field reaches max age.

I'd like to know if it's the same for TCN BPDUs on their way up to the root bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that true TCN BPDUs were only used in the original STP. RSTP uses RST BPDUs with the TC bit set which have message/max age fields and are discarded when aged out.

True TCN BPDUs have no age fields, but as far as I understand it, they're not forwarded. A bridge receiving a TCN BPDU may (and probably will) decide to send TCN BPDUs on its own though.

Answer (score 0):

The Topology Change Notification BPDU doesn't have a message age field.  This is the format from the IEEE 802.1D-2004 standard:

1. The Protocol Identifier is encoded in Octets 1 and 2 . It takes
   the value 0000 0000 0000 0000.
2. The Protocol Version Identifier
   is encoded in Octet 3 . It takes the value 0000 0000.
3. The BPDU Type is encoded in Octet 4.  This field takes the value 1000 0000 (where bit 8 is shown at the left of the sequence). This denotes a Topology Change Notification BPDU.